# Error when register Yubikey Bio with website

Tags: yubikey, fido2

I am having an issue registering a yubikey bio with a website. I have managed to register a Yubikey 5 series with the website without issue however when I try with the Yubikey bio I get an error like the one below (it occurs in both edge and Firefox):

[image: error message]

Error message reads: This security key doesn't look familiar. Please try a different one.

The yubikey appears to be working fine when I test it on demo.yubico.com. I setup the Yubikey and added fingerprints on a windows machine however not the same machine I am currently using the Yubikey on. Does anyone have any ideas how I would go about getting edge/firefox to let me register this yubikey with a website?

Edit: The issue persists across multiple websites not just vault.bitwarden.com however it does not occur when using demo.yubico.com.

Comment: How have you added the fingerprints? On Windows you have two options, one is to register the fingerprints with Windows the other with the stick. The first just uses the fingerprint reader the latter uses it as FIDO2 device.

Comment: I think I just registered them with Windows. I followed the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fp96iTxk0RU

Comment: You have to setup the YubiKey on each machine. Try it on the machine where it was originally configured.

Comment: The instructions you linked to are device specific linkage. Which is the reason your getting the message the security key is unfamiliar

Comment: So can this key be setup to be host independent so that I can use it on multiple machines or do I have to set it up on every machine I use it?

Comment: @John554 As you have registered your fingerprints in the key the key should work host independent but you have to register it on every site you want to use it.